# Popup window in any app

Tags: android, android-widget

i want to Popup dialog at a specific time in any app my code :

```
 public class testPOPDialog extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);



}
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(testPOPDialog.this)
            .setTitle("tanchulai")
            .setMessage("bucuo de tanchulai")

            .create();

        d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        d.show();     
       }
    };

}
```

it give me

```
12-03 10:12:18.162: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(571): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRoot$W@43dd71c0 -- permission denied for this window type
```

what is this permission
if i delete `d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);` my app is correct.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this permission to your manifest:

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

Comment: I've added the permission and used the exact same code. It is able to show dialog when within app, however if I go to home screen or other apps, it does not show on the screen (going back to the app I can see the pop up). What is missing?

Comment: I got it working by using getApplicationContext() instead of testPOPDialog.this in Topic owner's code... no idea why

Comment: Answer is Not Work for Marshmallow and above

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks to `Mathias Lin`

I am new to Android so it was hard to me to set permission knowing from `Mathias Lin`'s answer.
Because I didn't know how to set permission and where in the manifest file.

Finally I did it by help of `Mathias Lin`'s answer. So I made the answer elaborate.

---

In mainfest file use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

after

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion=...
    android:targetSdkVersion=... />
```

as

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest file with the activity that you want to show as a pop-up. -->>

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,my question is want to pop dialog No matter what programs are running ,like a Clock application.when the   specific time is come .it can pop a dialog