# Fetch and parse USSD response data

Tags: android, ussd

I am trying to parse USSD response by carrier network.Found a link https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor
but it does not support for 4.2.2 and above. Is there any api or method to attain such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to get response, Basically a background "Accessibility Service" is running which receives callback by the system whenever system accessible events are fired and app filter out the event when alert dialogue after calling USSD which in our case "android.app.AlertDialog" is shown and at this instance we can retrieve the data sent by the operator.
             "Accessibility Service" for particular app needs to be enabled manually by the end user not programmatically by code because of security purpose mentioned by android.

Comment: You can also follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/34132708/2648780. If you got any other issue let me know.