# How to read USSD Message response in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ussd

i want to store my balance in `sqlite`  database i am successfully dial the USSD

```
String balance_check="*444";
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
  String ussd = balance_check + encodedHash;
 startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

Here is onActivityResult function

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String dd = data.toString();
            Log.d("myussdmessage", data.toString());}}
```

but I cannot get the string exactly how to do it.I want to store the balance form the dialogue to my database.Can any one suggest me how to do it.

Comment: You should create `AccessibilityService` for that.

Comment: can u share some link for that

Comment: yup [check this](https://github.com/manishpatelgt/NetworkInfoRepo). all app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build an AccessibilityService in order to do that you need to read the documentation of AccessibilityService in below link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

and also this question helped me

[Prevent USSD dialog and read USSD response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057625/prevent-ussd-dialog-and-read-ussd-response)