# how to get ussd response in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I have a flutter project that requires to run USSD codes in flutter as direct way to access mobile money of any carrier through my flutter app. USSD codes are mostly used in african countries. i came across an SDK called userhover but there are non documentation on how to use the SDK in flutter

Comment: Please read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912452/how-to-read-ussd-message-response-in-android), and then you can write custom platform-specific code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/ussd_service) author here.

Since Android API level 26, the method [sendUssdRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#sendUssdRequest(java.lang.String,%20android.telephony.TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) is exposed to make silent USSD requests.

I made a Flutter plugin called [ussd_service](https://pub.dev/packages/ussd_service) to be able to easily access it from dart in a Flutter application. It can be used in the following manner:

```dart
import 'package:ussd_service/ussd_service.dart';

makeMyRequest() async {
  int subscriptionId = 1; // sim card subscription Id
  String code = "*21#"; // ussd code payload
  try {
    String ussdSuccessMessage = await UssdService.makeRequest(subscriptionId, code);
    print("succes! message: $ussdSuccessMessage");
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print("error! code: ${e.code} - message: ${e.message}");
  }
};

makeMyRequest();
```

If you are targeting only Android, this could be helpful. Unfortunately, iOS doesn't support running silent USSD requests.
Let me know on the [Github repo](https://github.com/vkammerer/ussd_service)'s issues if you have any issue with it.

Comment: but this package doesn't work on android APIs less than 26...is there a way to make it work??

Comment: sendUssdRequest was added with API level 26, so if you need to support previous versions, you have to use another plugin

Answer (score 1):

There is an android SDK called [Hover](https://www.usehover.com/), it helps to automate USSD sessions in the background of Android applications.The SDK can run virtually any USSD interaction on any mobile operator anywhere in the world. This includes mobile money, airtime topup etc.

[Here's](https://medium.com/use-hover/how-to-integrate-hover-sdk-with-flutter-a5b0b8be5c85) a tuto of how to integrate it in flutter