# Is it possible to select USSD response menu item in android?

Tags: android, ussd

I am following this link
[Prevent USSD dialog and read USSD response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057625/prevent-ussd-dialog-and-read-ussd-response?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
to send USSD request to our netwrok provider, read response and prevent USSD dialog.This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String encodedStar = Uri.encode("*");
        String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");

        startService(new Intent(this, USSDService.class));
        call(encodedStar+"XXXX" + encodedHash);
    }
    protected void call(String phoneNumber) {
        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber)));
    }
}
```

It works fine. As a response it gives me another menu to select what to do. there are 4 options like this.

```
1. A 
2. B
3. C
4. D
```

Now I want to send the my response 1 or 2 to nework provider and get final response. 
Plese help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any luck with this thread?

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same question and the solution was to send the option with the first call.
in your case

```
call(encodedStar+"XXXX" +encodedStar+'1'+ encodedHash);
```

I hope this will help someone.