# Undismissable Android dialog

Tags: android, view, dialog, dismiss

I need an undismissable Android dialog or a view that can't be canceled.
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344523/popup-window-in-any-app) works unless I hold the Home button and switch to another application.

Is it possible to keep a dialog or a view above everything unless the application providing the dialog is killed or the device is restarted/switched off?

Comment: That would be very user-unfriendly I think...

Comment: Use activity with dialog theme plus service which will check if your dialog-actiivity is on top and if not - place it on top.

Comment: This is not best practice.. indeed you could say that this is worst practice...

Comment: Can't you just a frame of a ImageView etc. on top of everything 9handling the back button also). That way this can be dismissed if you press only the Home or Multitasking button etc. I don't know what's the purpose of it, but it can be done (if you Override the `onBackPressed`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I needed to lock the device, I ended up by using [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) that allows to lock the device with a password.