# Android: How to access display (Activity) of different app that is not shown in upper layer

Tags: android, root

Hello Android developers,

Im more or less expierenced in Android programming and now i want to create an app that is allowed to access the display of another app or the activity that is less my app. Both apps should be active, should run. My app shall access the display data of the other app (also can be android system display), change it a bit and then show it again.

Is it possible without root rights?
Is there any Android support class that could help me? Which way i can go?
I hope my problem is clear and you can help me!

Ok now I have a more detailed question: How can open my app and show a transparent RelativeLayout, so that you can see what is below my app?

Thankyou a lot

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both applications are yours, you can access the other Activity using a connection between them (sockets, pipes, shared files, etc.)

If you'd like to create an overlay and display something on top of the other app, you can do that using a 'system window' popup. For example: [Popup window in any app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344523/popup-window-in-any-app)

If the other app is an arbitrary software without any modifications, such thing is not possible as it would lead to security issues. Both applications are Unix processes running in their own sandboxes without any direct communication.

Comment: Thankyou very much. That helped a bit. Here a more detailed question: How can open my app and show a transparent RelativeLayout, so that you can see what is below my app? Only setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) does not do it.

Comment: you can see what's below in Android launcher screen if you make your app's launch screen semi or completely transparent. But at that point, no other app window is visible (Android shows only one app window at a time or a split window of 2 apps which are non-overlapping). I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but you if you are trying to show an overlay over a camera picture taken, then you need to the picture byte stream and draw on a canvas and on top of that draw whatever you like. And as @Zielony has mentioned, you can always show a popup which is more generic.